# glide.js - Show/hide (filter) slides?

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know how to go about selectively showing and hiding (toggling) slides in glide.js?

There is a method `removeItem()` which can remove slides but it is more of a permanent removal than a hide and I do not know how to get them back. I've tried the `refresh()` method in hopes that it would restore the Glider instance to it's original condition with all slides showing but it does not do that.

Ideally I'd like to give each slide a class name (e.g. location1, location2,...) and then have a user controlled input such as a checkbox to show only the slides for the selected locations.

Comment: Not a glide.js user. From the docs they seem to use quite standard DOM. have you tried setting the slides `display:none`

Comment: @eamanola Yes tried that but it messes up the slider